# How to display expand icon for parent nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display an expand icon in between the above 2 'td's, if a td classvalue is 'indent0' , and the next td class values are 'indent1', 'indent2'; 
            where indent0 - denotes parent node , indent1 - child , indent2 - grand child.

```
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
                            <tbody>
                <?  foreach ( $aspects as $a ) {?>
                    <tr class="js-data-selector"
                                    data-taxonomy-id="<?=$a['taxonomy_id']?>">
                                    <td width="0.5">
                            <?draw_note_icon ();                                                                                ?>
                        </td> <td class="indent<?=$a['indent']?>">
                       <?=$a['aspect_label']?>: <span class="aspect-data" data-taxonomy-id="<?=$a['taxonomy_id']?>"></span></td>
                                </tr>
                          <?}?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>



                Example 

                A - indent0
                B - indent0
                C - indent1
                D - indent1
                E - indent0
                F - indent1
                G - indent2
```

In the above example, B, E,F rows should display expand icon.
                    Is there any way to accomplish this using jquery.

Below is the jQuery I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    display_expand_icon();
    });


function display_expand_icon(){

     var parent_indent = $("table tr").find("td:eq(1)").prop("class").substring(6);
     $children = $("table tr td").nextUntil(function() { return $(this).find("td:eq(1)").prop("class") <= "indent"+parent_indent });
    $children.prepend(" <span ><img src="../images/expand.png"> ></span>");
}
```

Comment: You can use for loop instead of foreach to fetch and check if chilld exists.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can manipulate it while data gets rendered. No need to use jQuery. You can give it a try. Though it is very rigid code . You can make it more generalized.

```
function draw_note_icon($i) {
  global $aspects;
  $curr = $aspects[$i]['indent'];
  $nxt = isset($aspects[$i+1]['indent'])?$aspects[$i+1]['indent']:null;
  if(!is_null($nxt)) {
    if(in_array($nxt, array(2,1))) {
      if(($nxt == 2) ||  ($nxt == 1 && $curr != 1))
        echo '+';
    }
  }
}
```